# embed an image in a beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I am working on a corporate beamer theme, and I would like to embed images (background and company logo) directly in the theme: I dont want users to have to have it next to every presentation source.

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably only if somehow you can convert it into something that tikz can render. For the version I'm working on (on and off) the company logo actually is in a font that for some reason cannot really be access by anything other than lualatex. Plus we cannot distribute the font. So I converted the few chars there were in the font into svg and was luckily enough that this data could be copyed and rendered by tikz (tikz cannot render all possible svgs)

Comment: In the file tree of your beamer sty-files you can also include a directory with the images (pdf, png, etc) and include as normal graphics with relative links. Then the installation of the theme includes both the sty-files and the graphics, and the user will not be bothered with it.

Comment: The answer is, yes it is possible, as mentioned in the previous comments. Did these help ?

Comment: @BambOo I suppose StefanH answer is the good one, but I have not had the occasion to experiment with it: I had to switch to something else, and I never came back to this beamer theme (priorities, you know :( )

Comment: Ok, then I believe this question should be closed for the moment, as it lacks information about what you have tried so far and is therefore a bit broad. But if this topic pops back into your priorities, please feel free to edit your question and it will surely be reopened. Do you agree with this ?

Comment: Yes, this should be closed. (How can I do it myself in case it occurs again?)